# Get my uploaded youtube list with PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm reading into the v3 Youtube Api from Google (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) but I can't for the life of me find out how I can get my uploaded list back.

I have made an API key etc. And it all works properly when I collect one video(by ID).
The thing is, though, that I just want to receive my total uploaded video's list.

It seems, however, that you NEED to send an ID along. If you don't you get the following error:

```
"domain": "youtube.parameter",
"reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
"message": "No filter selected.",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": ""
```

I've tried using playlist in `fields` and I've tried using just list in my `fields` parameter, to no avail. (like such: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=APIKEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&fields=list )

The only thing I keep getting is one video if I use its ID.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried your account Id.ps this is just a guess

Answer (score 1):

First you'll call [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with [mine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) = true and get [uploads playlist id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

Then with [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the [playlistId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId), you'll get the list items.

If you want to get further details on videos, you can do [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with specifying [video ids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id), you got from the previous call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My inexperience with oAuth leaves me to think that all the Oauths and CURL or Zend stuff I need to do to get a simple playlist is not worth the hassle. I was hoping I could just use a $.GET or $.POST with Javascript/jQuery to get it but authing etc is just too much work for such a simple feature. I could write a crawler faster :-p

Comment: Oh, by the way. I specifically asked for the not-playlist but just the uploaded list.